# surrogate key implementation in fact table

Tags: surrogate-key

i am so new to warehousing
i have problem in implementing surrogate key. for example i have a Customer Dimension table which has a surrogate key for each customer in a specific region.
like this:
  (SK_     NK_       Customer_     Region) (
  1  ,  10022   ,      22     ,     100)
  (2  ,  10162    ,     62     ,     101)
 ( 3  ,  10322     ,    22     ,     103) ,
                    .
                    .
                    .
these are saved in my customer dimension table. my question is that how can i calculate the surrogate key to be registered as foreign key in my fact table when a transaction happens?

Answer (score 0):

If a transaction belongs to a single customer then you would place the key to the customer dimension table in the fact table.